# Get data from a node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Picture of my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKpE4.jpg)

how do I *retrieve* the *values* ​​from the **user1** (**posts**) *node* and *add* them to the **listview**?

I tried this code below, but I do not know what to do next

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
.getReference("user1")
.child("posts")
.addValueEventListener(

 );
```

Comment: Did you try anything already? If so, edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If not, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/ and https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postsRef = rootRef.child("users").child("user1").child("posts");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String body = ds.child("body").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(title + " / " +  body);
            Log.d("TAG", title + " / " +  body);
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
postsRef .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The data that will be displayed is:

```
Xxxx / Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Xxxxx / Xxxxxxxxxx
```